# Swift:- Increment label value by 1 on button click in custom tableview cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift4

I am trying to increase label value by 1 on button click which is inside custom table cell. I am able to change values differently in different cells but the problem is if I tap + in first cell label changes from 0 to 1, when I tap + in second cell label directly changes from 0 to 2 and so on in other cells. How can I fix this?

```
     var counts = 0

    @IBAction func addPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
    let cell = tblview.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! HomeDetailsTableViewCell
    counts = (counts + 1)
    cell.lblNoOfItems.text = "\(counts)"
}
```

Comment: This is because every time you are using the global `count` variable to set the value in each `UITableViewCell's` `label`. So the update value of `count` is used on each click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be 2 ways to achieve this:

**1.** Keep the count of each cell in an `Array` at the `controller` level and each time you press the `button`, get the count from array and use that, i.e.

```
var counts = [Int](repeating: 0, count: 10) //10 is the number of cells here

@IBAction func addPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
    let cell = tblview.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! HomeDetailsTableViewCell
    counts[indexPath.row] += 1
    cell.lblNoOfItems.text = "\(counts[indexPath.row])"
}
```

**2.** Keep the count of each cell in the custom cell itself, i.e. in `HomeDetailsTableViewCell`, i.e.

```
class HomeDetailsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var count = 0
    //Rest of the code...
}

@IBAction func addPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
        let cell = tblview.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! HomeDetailsTableViewCell
        cell.count += 1
        cell.lblNoOfItems.text = "\(cell.count)"
}
```

Also, the way you are implementing the code for adding `+ button` is not correct. You must implement it within the `HomeDetailsTableViewCell` itself, i.e.

```
class HomeDetailsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var lblNoOfItems: UILabel!
    var count = 0

    @IBAction func addPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.count += 1
        self.lblNoOfItems.text = "\(self.count)"
    }
    //Rest of the code...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get this question's answer using below code in **Swift 5**

**// 1st Step**

Inside Your **TableViewCell**

```
import UIKit

@objc protocol CellDelagate : NSObjectProtocol {

    func addPressed(_ cell: TableViewCell)
}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var cellDelagate: CellDelagate?
    var indexPath : IndexPath?
    @IBOutlet weak var gPaybutton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var proceesingLabel: UILabel!

    var count = 0

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    @IBAction func proccessingButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        self.cellDelagate!.addPressed(self)
        if gPaybutton.tag == indexPath?.row {

        }
    }
}
```

**// 2nd Step**

Inside Your **ViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, CellDelagate {

    func addPressed(_ cell: TableViewCell) {

        cell.count += 1
        cell.proceesingLabel.text = "Processing : \(cell.count)"
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return yourArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell")! as? TableViewCell//1.

        cell?.indexLabel?.text = yourArray[indexPath.row] //2.
        cell?.cellDelagate = self //3.
        cell?.tag = indexPath.row //4.
        return cell! //5.
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tested your code but that line "self.cellDelagate!.addPressed(self)" throws the following error: "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

**This is because you're using a global variable for all the cells in your class if you want to maintain the count differently for each cell you have to use different variables for each cell, I'm just giving you the directions so find your way** .

Create a data source for your count and initialise it with the same datasource you are using for your table like, suppose you have a array of string for your tableview data source lets create list array that contains your title and count with it. I'm giving you all the steps in my solution you just have to put the code at the right place : -

```
//Suppose this is your tableivew data source
let list : [String] = ["Title1","Title2","Title3"]

//Make a dictionary that is going to be your datasource of tableview holding the count too
var listDict : [[String:Any]] = []
for item in list{
    let dict : [String:Any] = ["title":item,"count":Int(0)]
    listDict.append(dict)
}

//Where you are performing the actions like in didSelectRow or in any button
let cellIndexPath : IndexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0) // Get the indexPath of Cell

//Update the count
if let count = listDict[cellIndexPath.row]["count"] as? Int{
    let newValue = count + 1
    listDict[cellIndexPath.row]["count"] = newValue
}

//Reload the tableview cell of update manually your choice I'm reloading the cell for short
let tableview = UITableView()
tableview.reloadRows(at: [cellIndexPath], with: .fade)
```